# Query where a column displays the first entry in each table in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the query I'm starting with (originally found [here](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-table-columns-in-database)):

```
select schema_name(tab.schema_id) as schema_name,
    tab.name as table_name, 
    col.column_id,
    col.name as column_name, 
    t.name as data_type,    
    col.max_length,
    col.precision
from sys.tables as tab
    inner join sys.columns as col
        on tab.object_id = col.object_id
    left join sys.types as t
    on col.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
order by schema_name,
    table_name, 
    column_id;
```

Here's the current sample output which provides an overview of all the tables in a database:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to add three columns on the right titled the following:
**FirstEntry, SecondEntry, and ThirdEntry.**

These just display the first three entries located within the column being represented.

Comment: @Dale : I think the poster wants the first 3 column values, but doesn't specify ordering

Comment: given I could see no possible use of this, I think the poster might have an XY problem....

Comment: @Dale: That's correct, I'm just looking to add the top three values in each column so I quickly scan the different tables in a new database.

Comment: @Rb99 you're going to have to build yourself a dynamic query to obtain that information. So for each row create a sub-query for that table and column. Then put that together with the query you have above as a massive dynamic query which you then run. Way too big a job for anyone here to do for you. I'm sure I've seen it done before but my google-foo is not finding it right now.